# What is wrong with my conditional statement for qmake?

Tags: c++, qt

main.cpp is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
#ifdef CONDITION
    std::cout << "built in debug mode" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

And the .pro file is:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp

debug:DEFINES += "CONDITION"
```

The problem is that both release and debug builds output:

```
built in debug mode
```

What am I missing?

According to [qmake documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html)

> You may also use the : operator to perform single line conditional
>   assignments; for example:
>
> ```
> win32:DEFINES += QT_DLL
> ```

EDIT:

Changing

```
debug:DEFINES += CONDITION
```

to

```
DEBUG:DEFINES += "CONDITION"
```

fixes the problem. Why this is so remains a mystery, since I have:

```
CONFIG+=debug
```

and **not**

```
CONFIG+=DEBUG
```

argument for qmake with the debug configuration.

Also in the documentation they use lowercase: e.g.

```
macx:debug {
     HEADERS += debugging.h
 }
```

Comment: Maybe 'debug' is not a valid qualifier? Have you checked the documentation for the valid qualifiers? Maybe you need to write it in all capitals? `DEBUG:DEFINES`.

Comment: who defines `debug`? where? How are you compiling this?

Comment: @TheCodeArtist I deduced from the documentation that "debug" is defined automatically. Apparently it is not the case. The correct flag is "DEBUG".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forum post (http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-6028.html) suggests, that you may need to use `qDebug` or simply `!release`. This is entirely untested, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Both qDebug and !release work. Thank you! But I have no idea why, since I explicitly put CONFIG+=debug.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik While I'm not entirely sure, maybe the inliners only work for predefined symbols. QMake probably doesn't recognize a combination, which does not 'fit perfectly'. Also, if your problem was solved, it'd be nice if you accepted the answer and thereby mark your problem as solved. Thank you.